# Meaning of centering horizontally or vertically in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Android documentation says:

android:layout_centerVertical:

If true, centers this child vertically within its parent.

I found this used everywhere.
 What exactly does 'centering vertically' or 'centering horizontally' mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are parameters that specify how a view is centered in a RelativeLayout. The relative layout containing the view uses the value of these layout parameters to determine where to position the view on the screen.

- Centering vertically `android:layout_centerVertical` - means the view object will be placed in the vertical center (the center from top to bottom) of the RelativeLayout.
- Centering horizontally `android:layout_centerHorizontal` - means the view object will be placed in the horizontal center (the center from left to right) of the RelativeLayout.

FYI: You can use the `android:layout_centerInParent` within the Relativelayout to center the view both vertically and horizontally at the same time.

I found this nice [article on RelativeLayout](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/relative-layout) helpful when I was learning. I recommend you check it out.

NOTE: If the view is not contained within a relative layout, these attributes are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Those attributes are related to [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative):

- centering vertically - putting your view in the center of the parent according to its height.
- centering horizontally - putting your view the center of your parent according to its width.

Comment: Moreover, `layout_centerVertical` is only valid for RelativeLayouts.